# How to detect a modifier key press in java on application startup, BEFORE any visual component exists?

Tags: java, keyboard

How can I detect a modifier key press (e.g. shift or alt) in java during application startup, BEFORE any visual component exists?

Depending on the pressed modifier key, I want to create, or not create a visual component.

NOTE: At the time I want to check the modifier key press, **there is no component to attach a KeyListener to**!

Comment: you should attach the listener to the JFrame itself

Comment: Hi abcOfJava. As mentioned, there is no visual component at that time, not even a JFrame. The check for a pressed modifier key happens in the first couple of lines of the main() method. There it decides whether to create a visual component, or not.

Comment: have you tried setting the visibility of the JFrame first to false then set it to true when a key is entered by the user?

Comment: As I said - at the time of the test there IS NO JFrame. But you mean that I create an empty one, leave it invisible, but attach a KeyListener to it, which I can then use to make the test. That could work. I'll check it out.

Comment: Isn't there a low level keyboard adapter that I can inquire WITHOUT a KeyListener? StdIn or something?